# three.js fontloader not work on ios

Tags: ios, three.js

```
loadFont() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.FontLoader.load(
            fontParams.url,
            (response) => {
                console.log('loadfont')
                this.font = response
                this.createTextMaterials()
                this.createNumberList()
                console.log('loadfont')
                resolve(response)
            }, (xhr) => {
                console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    })
}
```

it worked on android,but not on IOS,i test it on iphone5 and iphone6.
the debugging Always display:"request begin"

i print the err:

> {"target":{"onabort":null, "onloadstart":null, "ontimeout":null,
>   "onloadend":null, "onreadystatechange":null, "readyState":1,
>   "response":null, "responseText":null, "responseType":"",
>   "responseXML":null, "status":0, "statusText":"", "upload":{},
>   "withCredentials":false}}

[err mseeage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms2MR.jpg)

Comment: Could be helpful if you provide us with more info, like debug logs and errors given by the program..

Comment: the Error object just that.there is no more error message~~~

Comment: can you check the url from which you are requesting the resource? response is null...The resource is no longer available or the url is wrong.

Comment: i have check the url,it worked，i test it on andriod and browser.

Comment: on the same server,i test the  JSONLoader,  the JSONLoader is wored fine.